# Storing player turn in Zobrist hash

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, hash-function, game-ai

I'm currently implementing a Transposition table in a Chinese Checkers minimax algorithm.  In Chinese Checkers, no pieces are captured, and the board is functionally 81 spaces large.  Players take turn moving pieces across the board.

Part of the process involves creating a hash for the board state.  So far, I've got a functioning method that creates a (hopefully) unique hash for each board state:

```
 myHash = 0;
 //randoms[81][3] is an array filled completely with pseudorandom values
 for (int x = 0; x < 81; x++) {
      myHash ^= randoms[x][board[x]]; 
      //board[x] is the piece at space x (1=player1 piece, 2=player2 piece, 0=empty)
 }
```

More importantly, I do this incrementally in the applyMove function (and the undoMove function):

```
applyMove(int to, int from) {

   //Undo the 'from' piece in the hash
   myHash ^= randoms[from][board[from]];
   // Apply the move
   std::swap(board[from], board[to]);
   //Add the 'to' piece to the hash
   myHash ^= randoms[to][board[to]];

   // Update whose turn it is
   swapTurn();
 }
```

This works because of the reversibility property of the XOR function.

The issue I have now, is that the **hash function doesn't store whose turn it is**.  That is, you could have two identical game boards, but they would return different values in the minimax algorithm because one's trying to maximize the score, and the other is trying to minimize it.

Basically, my question is this:  How can I store the player's turn in an incrementally generated hash function, while keeping the ability to reverse it perfectly (and preferably inexpensively)?  Assuming the player's turn is an integer rather than a boolean, since the game will eventually have 6 players rather than two players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `turns[6]` array filled with pseudorandom values:

```
unsigned n = 6;  // number of players;

myHash ^= turns[active_player];           // 'undo' the old active player
active_player = (active_player + 1) % n;  // new active player's index
myHash ^= turns[active_player];           // 'add' new active player
```

this is similar to the piece position incremental update and works for `n` ∈ [2, 6].

---

As a side note...

usually Zobrist hashing is done by scanning the location of pieces, **excluding** empty squares. The location of empty squares isn't explicitly hashed.

So you could use a smaller (more cache-friendly) array. Something like:

```
std::uint64_t randoms[81][2];  // two players

for (unsigned x(0); x < 81; ++x)
  if (board[x])
    myHash ^= randoms[x][board[x]];
```

Comment: Thanks, that should work perfectly!  Also, I didn't consider the fact that I only had to hash the filled squares, that should definitely save some space.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you could store the turn state as a bit at the beginning of the hash...

```
inline bool GetTurn(int hash){
  return (bool)(hash & 1);
}
```

and have the Zobrist hash keys in the array all have 0 for their least significant bit, ex. `[[0x2348dec2, 0x93857e34, ....] ...]`